# Find and replace only first word as 'MNC.' Not 'Which' using selection.Repace

Tags: excel, vba

For a long time, I have been struggling to find a way to replace the first word as 'MNC.' instead of 'Which' in VBA code using the selection.replace method.

[image]

I need assistance on how to achieve the desired result of replacing only 'MNC.' using the provided code. I have been unsuccessful in obtaining the desired outcome as shown in the code below.

I appreciate your help in resolving this issue. Thank you.

```
Sub ReplaceAll_TEST()

    ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.Replace What:="*Client Name", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
        
End Sub
```

I need assistance on how to achieve the desired result of replacing only 'MNC.' using the provided code.

Comment: Can you add a before and an expected after picture? What you described and the code you posted are quite different.

Comment: Does replacing `What:="*Client Name"` by `What:="Client Name "` give you the expected result? Regard the space after "Client Name"

Comment: Yes, Ike, but I only want to display "MNC." without the rest. I need to use the star symbol "*" before "Client Name" to indicate the following sentence: 
There is only into one cell in Excel containing the text - 
"Please see the client name is MNC.
Kindly let me know if the client name which I provided is not what you expected." 

The desired result should show "MNC." and exclude the word "which". Hope you understand and please help

Comment: I have made some edits and added a 'before' and an 'expected' picture as well. Please take a look at the picture and let us know. I apologize for the previous edits, and I hope there won't be any further modifications. Thank you for your patience

Comment: What does *and exclude the word "which"* mean since you're just returning `MNC.`?

Comment: Yes, returning 'MNC'. I mean I want to display only word after finding the initial 'Client Name'.

Comment: This is not helpful, do you have idea what code to reverse the search in relation to your existing code

Comment: In the picture you added, the word immediately after "client name" is not "MNC", it is "is".

Answer (score 1):

### Extract String Between Two Strings

- The following illustrates how simple it is by using `Worksheet.Evaluate` with some of the 'new' (2022) Microsoft 365 text functions (`TEXTBEFORE`, `TEXTAFTER`).
- It is based on the following Excel formula:

  ```
  =IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A2:A11,"Please see the client name is "),".")&".","")
  ```

```vb
Sub ExtractNames()

    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "B" ' use 'A' to overwrite
    Const LEFT_DELIMITER As String = "Please see the client name is "
    Const RIGHT_DELIMITER As String = "."
    Const IFERROR_STRING As String = ""
    Const APPEND_RIGHT_DELIMITER As Boolean = True
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL)
        rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount > 0 Then
            Set rg = .Resize(rCount)
        End If
    End With
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim EvalString As String: EvalString = "IFERROR(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(" _
        & rg.Address & ",""" & LEFT_DELIMITER & """),""" _
        & RIGHT_DELIMITER & """)&""" _
        & IIf(APPEND_RIGHT_DELIMITER, "" & RIGHT_DELIMITER & "", "") _
        & """,""" & IFERROR_STRING & """)"
    
    'Debug.Print EvalString
    
    rg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN).Value = ws.Evaluate(EvalString)
   
    MsgBox "Names extracted.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all Derrick with Monisha if that's what you want:

```
Public Sub ReplaceAll_TEST()
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Replace _
        What:="Derrick", _
        Replacement:="Monisha", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```